# How do i replace a column in a numpy array with 0 given that the column contains the number 0?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a program that replaces entire columns of matrices if the column contains a 0.

I tried making a numpy array, x, and running the command:

```py
x[:, np.where(x <= 0)] = 0
```

The desired outcome would be that the sum of all columns containing 0 would be 0.

Answer (score 1):

```py
X[:, (X==0).any(axis=0)]=0
```

Explanation
`(X==0)` is matrix of booleans of the same shape than X, saying if each element of X is 0
`(X==0).any()` says is True iff at least of those booleans is True
`(X==0).any(axis=0)` does that only along axis 0, so it gives an array of n booleans, one per columns, each of them True iff one boolean of `X==0` is True in that column.
`X[:, (X==0).any(axis=0)]` are all rows of columns that are `True` in the previous array, that is that contain a 0.
So `X[:, (X==0).any(axis=0)]=0` puts everything to 0 in those columns